# Matlab colorbar with two axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I'm using the mapping toolbox to create a contour plot with `contourfm()` `contourcbar()` and `caxis()` to label the colorbar. What is the best way to add a second axis to the colorbar so that it looks something like this?

[image: A mock up of a two-axis colorbar]

If it makes a difference, I'm running Matlab v2014b on RHEL6 with -nodesktop and -nodisplay. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: I used Benoit_11's answer to come up with some example code to reproduce the problem. Wait for the plot to be created, then re-size the figure window. You'll see that the second colorbar axis (left side) doesn't scale properly with the rest of the plot. Any advice to fix this would greatly appreciated!

```
figure('Color','white')
worldmap('north america')
load topo
R = georasterref('RasterSize',[180 360], 'Latlim',[0 80],'Lonlim',[-160 -50]);

contourfm(topo, R, -7000:1000:3000)
caxis([-8000 4000])


hBar1 = contourcbar
contourcmap('jet')
caxis([1 10])
BarPos = get(hBar1,'position');
ylabel(hBar1,'Total electron content','FontSize',12);
haxes = axes('position',BarPos,'color','none','ytick',0:5:15,'ylim',[0 
15],'xtick',[]);
ylabel('Approximate position error','FontSize',12)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a 2nd axes with the same position as the 1st colorbar and set its `ylabel` property to the title you want plus the `ytick` property to what you need.

Dummy example:

```
%// Create colorbar
hBar1 = colorbar;

%// Set its ylabel property
ylabel(hBar1,'Total electron content','FontSize',12);

%// Get its position
BarPos = get(hBar1,'position');

%// Create an axes at the same position
haxes = axes('position',BarPos,'color','none','ytick',0:5:15,'ylim',[0 
15],'xtick',[]);

%// Set its ylabel property
ylabel('Approximate position error','FontSize',12)
```

output (cropped):

[image]

You just need to figure out the correct placement of the colorbar so that it does not overlap with the axes containing your plots. Note that the black line at the bottom left comes from the empty axes so it won't be there in your case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Your dummy example produces exactly what I'm looking for, but when I tried using `axes()` with the colorbar position in context with the rest of my code, the scaling of the two axes don't match (the "Approximate Position Error" axis is taller than the colorbar and the other axis). I have a feeling it might be because I'm using `contourcbar` to produce the colorbar. I'll embed a picture in the original post. Thanks again!

Comment: I figured out that the issue with scaling the second axes is caused by re-sizing the figure window. The second axis doesn't scale correctly with the rest of the plot. See my example code in "Edit 1". In my code, I'm using `print` to save the image pragmatically with a custom resolution (with `-r` option), but re-sizing the figure window also demonstrates the scaling problem.